# Application name at startup in colourful text and proper pattern in console

Tags: c, stdout

I want to add application name in specific pattern with text colour at the time of starting the application on console. Pattern is similar to below example.

```
                                    _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
```

Is there any library or API in C?

Comment: There's nothing entirely portable (i.e., in the C standard). What's your target environment?

Comment: The question is why? When i use the console i expect the application to just output the necessary information. If i want colorful images and wasteful splash screen I'd be using GUI applications.

Comment: @RedX you are right. But I just want application name at the time of starting. Many console based application have this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VT100 commands. Good example here: http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=1278116